# C# - How to read string value from the custom resource provider?

Tags: c#, resources, localization

I created a custom resource provider by following guidelines from the following link:
http://asp-net-whidbey.blogspot.com/2006/03/aspnet-20-custom-resource-provider.html

On .aspx pages I'm using the following code and it work fine:

```
<asp:Literal ID="ltlFoo" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:SomeText %>" />
```

Now I'd like to read the localized value from the code:

```
string foo = Resources.GetString("SomeText");
```

The problem is that I don't know how to instantiate the resource manager.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**
I used the following code and it works great:

```
string foo = (string)GetGlobalResourceObject("", "SomeText");
```

Is there any reason why I should not use that code?

Answer (score 1):

So your resource manager should have a name and you should be able to do something similar to the following.

```
 // Create a resource manager to retrieve resources.
        ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("items", 
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());


 // Retrieve the value of the string resource named "welcome".
 // The resource manager will retrieve the value of the  
 // localized resource using the caller's current culture setting.
 String foo = rm.GetString("SomeText");
```

[Taken From MSDN Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d17ax2xk.aspx)